# How to Calculate ColdFusion Cached Template Memory Consumption

Tags: coldfusion

Specifically I'm trying to figure out a rough way to calculate a good value, relative to JVM settings, for *CF Admin > Server Settings > Caching > Maximum number of cached templates*.

So what I'm trying to figure out is whether or not it's possible to use the Admin API to get this information from ColdFusion? Or, if there's another way using Java for instance.
The only guidance I've found is from [Adobe's documentation suggesting 1 template per megabyte allocated to the JVM](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ff9).

Please no answers about profiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "JVM Settings" do you know which part of the generation you are interested in.  The New or Young generation, Old or Tenured generation or the Permanent generation? Also, what are you looking to achieve?

Comment: after observing with jConsole, and reviewing a heap dump, it appears the Old Generation is filling up with what appears to be entries from the template cache. My software product generates .cfm files - so it can easily fill the cache. I'm looking for a way to help my customers configure their ColdFusion servers. And, in this case I believe providing guidance around the template cache size will help them avoid OoM errors.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you can see some of the template cache usage in the CF Server Monitor, but you may also be able to use something http://www.cftracker.net/page.cfm/features to see what's getting used in your cache.

Comment: +1 for the attempt because I've not looked at the project before. Doesn't have anything that can help me however.